Different P-Value and AIC before/after standardization [Python - Statsmodels]
I am investigating the correlation between environmental variables (15 continuous variables grouped as 'DHIs' in the code below) and fox occurrence (binary), using logistic regression / Python statsmodels. I standardized the 15 environmental variables (denoted 'foxz' below) and compared the results of the logistic regression analysis before (first image) and after (second image) standardization. However, as shown below the P values and AIC were different before and after standardization.
import statsmodels.api as sm

X = fox[DHIs] 
Y = fox['occurrence'] 
print(sm.Logit(Y,X).fit().summary2())

X = foxz[DHIs] 
Y = foxz['occurrence'] 
print(sm.Logit(Y,X).fit().summary2())


However when I do this in R using the GLM library, I get the same P values and AIC after standardization, which seems logical.
Can anyone explain why this is the case? I've checked the standardization multiple times and there doesnt seem to be a problem with that, so it must be something with the statsmodel logistic regression package...

Did you accidentally standardize occurrence?

@Noah Thank you for the question. I checked multiple times but the occurrence is not standardized, only the explanatory variables are.

AFAICS, you are not including a constant in the regression. The constant is needed to compensate for the demeaning of explanatory variables.

@Josef good observation. Both models should have an intercept (which should not be standardized). The only difference between the standardized and unstandardized models should be that the coefficients and standard errors in the unstandardized model should be multiplied by the standard deviation of the corresponding predictor in the standardized model.

Why not post the data together with the code? Otherwise this is more of a guessing game. It's unproductive.

@Josef I tried it out and it worked, thank you!
